# Simplifying Linear Congruences

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I want to solve the given linear congruence

$$ 5x+1\equiv 2 \mod 6 $$

> **My Approach:**
>
> \begin{align}&\Rightarrow&  5x -1&\equiv 0\mod 6 \\
> &\Rightarrow&  6x -x-1&\equiv 0\mod6 \tag{ as $6\equiv 0\mod6$}\\
> &\Rightarrow&  0 -x-1&\equiv 0\mod6 \\
> &\Rightarrow& x&\equiv -1\mod 6 \end{align}

Am I correct till now ?? If I am correct, how to proceed further?

Comment: You are done. Then $x=5,11,17,\ldots$ and $x=-1,-7,-13,\ldots $.

Comment: @DietrichBurde  so i can write the same equation as $\Rightarrow  x\equiv 5\, \, mod\, \, 6 $
 ?

Comment: As you know, $5\equiv -1 \bmod 6$. We have $a\equiv b\bmod n$ iff $n\mid (b-a)$.